# Jupyter Notebook failed to run %qtconsole

Tags: python

When I run %qtconsole on jupyter notebook (I ran jupyter notebook  using Windows power-shell0

Error gives

```
 c:\users\mohit\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-  
 packages\IPython\utils\traitlets.py:5: 
 UserWarning: IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.
 warn("IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.")

c:\users\mohit\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\pickleutil.py:3: 
UserWarning: IPython.utils.pickleutil has moved to ipykernel.pickleutil
warn("IPython.utils.pickleutil has moved to ipykernel.pickleutil")

c:\users\mohit\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\jsonutil.py:3: 
UserWarning: IPython.utils.jsonutil has moved to jupyter_client.jsonutil
warn("IPython.utils.jsonutil has moved to jupyter_client.jsonutil")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

```
try:
    from IPython.parallel import bind_kernel
except ImportError:
    # technically possible, because parallel has higher pyzmq min-version
    pass
else:
    bind_kernel()
```

Then, in the next cell:

```
%qtconsole
```

For details you can type `qtconsole??` in Jupyter.

The import on top might give you this message:

```
/Users/reblochonmasque/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/parallel.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.parallel` package has been deprecated. You should import from ipyparallel instead.
  "You should import from ipyparallel instead.", ShimWarning)
```

But according to the docs, it is okay.

Comment: Really? It works here... Are you running the latest version? What does qtconsole?? tell you?

Comment: After running your code, and then running %qtconsole, it shows nothing, nothing happens. No qtconsole, no error. And after running qtconsole??, it shows a bar at bottom of my browser, it tell me source details.

Comment: I have already updated ipython, qtconsole and jupyter using pip command, but still gives problem.

Comment: Yes, it should not show anything, it linked a qtconsole to the notebook; you can now use it. :)  [there are good docs for the jupyter project, I suggest you take a quick look at them: https://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ )

Comment: but qtconsole is not opening.

Comment: And also there are some other problem with my Jupyter Notebook, such as Terminal Unavailable.